# Why does jQuery validation display the word 'false' instead of my custom message?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, jquery-validate

I have a jquery validation rule that looks like this:

```
NINumber: {
                required: true,
                remote: {
                    url:'/employee/isninumberunique',
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        'niNumber': function(){return $('#txtNINumber').val();}
                    }
                }
            }
```

and after my rules are defined I define the custom message like so:

```
messages: {
            NINumber : {
                remote: 'NI Number used by existing employee'
            }
        }
```

However, when the conditions are met for this to fail (the input is not unique), it instead displays the message 'false' like below

[image: image showing validation message of false]

my controller returns either true or false in JSON format and I know that the message is being read when the condition is met as I tried the following and the debugger line was hit.:

```
            messages: {
            NINumber : {
                remote: function(){
                    debugger;
                    return 'NI Number used by existing employee'
                }                  
            }
        }
```

why would it be reading the message to display and instead displaying the word 'false'?

Comment: The question is not very useful to others without being able to see the server-side code that was causing the issue.  Also FYI - you do not need the `data` parameter because the data from the field being validated is already being sent.  The `data` parameter is only used when other data also needs to be sent.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was that as my web controller was getting the true/false from the API controller then I was returning true or false as a string rather than as a bool. Once I'd converted the input to a bool and instead returned that, the validation worked as expected.